# How to return and display json data with getJSON properly?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, postal-code

file "zip.json":
    {
    "zip11111": "City1",
    "zip99999": "City2"
    }

the javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#textbox1zip").change(function() {
    $.getJSON('zip.json', function(data) {

    /* each of the following code blocks don't work when exchanged for each other:

    1 zipcode = "zip" + $("#textbox1zip").val();
    * $('#textbox2city').val( data.zipcode ); -----> call silently dropped

    2 zipcode = 'zip99999';
    * $('#textbox2city').val( data.zipcode ); -----> call silently dropped

    3 zipcode = "zip" + $("#textbox1zip").val();
    * alert( data.zipcode ); -----> returns 'undefined'
    */

    /* but each of these blocks here works:
    4 $('#textbox2city').val( data.zip99999 ); ------> ok

    5 alert( data.zip99999 ); -----> ok

    6 zipcode = 'zip99999';
    * $('#textbox2city').val( zipcode ); ------> ok

    7 zipcode = "zip" + $("#textbox1zip").val();
    * $('#textbox2city').val( zipcode ); ------> ok
    */
    });
});
});
```

I want the value taken from textbox1zip to return the appropriate value from "zip.json" into textbox2city. And I want to use getJSON. It's probably very simple, but I can't see it...

Comment: just use `console.log(data)` to see exactly what is being returned and then write based on that object

Comment: I go with adding brackets. Also thanks, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var zipcode = 'zip99999';   // or 'zip11111'
$('#textbox2city').val( data[zipcode] );
```

and

```
var zipcode = "zip" + $("#textbox1zip").val();
$('#textbox2city').val( data[zipcode] );
```

Now, this `alert( data.zipcode ); -----> returns 'undefined'`

This happen since the json object you have only two keys `zip11111` & `zip99999`. So, `data.zip11111` or `data.zip99999` works, whereas `data.zipcode` doesn't since there's no key with the name `zipcode`.

Comment: WORKS! And I understand the explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: It does, indeed! I am very impressed by the speed of your answer, too.

Comment: It's because I usually come across this issue in SO and that's why I already know the solution too :)

Comment: GJ, taking the time to explain. I woulda thought it CS. Sorry, lol. +1 to you good sir!